# How to URL Escape Relative URL in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When I go to get the following urls, there is a problem. I'm attempting to bookmark this site, but the first part of the URL does not appear after I run the code.

[image]

This is the code that I'm using to get the url from anamed's list of job titles. This parses the `href` attribute from the `a` tag.
[image]

Comment: so, add hostname to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its a relative link.

You could use something like that

```
base_url = "https://wuzzuf.net"
links.append(f"{base_url}{jobtitles[i].find('a').attrs['href']}")
```